# Downloading Second .ics file From Same Page Opens the Previously Saved One

Tags: icalendar

I have a page that among other things has *"Add to Calendar"* links.  These download Icalendar (.ics) events.  It's for a travel situation, so there can be two events (outbound and return journeys) and each is offered as a separate download.

If I click one (e.g. outbound) it downloads and offers it to open.  I do so and click save to calendar and it adds it to my calendar.  So far, so good.  Then I click the other one (return) and it downloads but when I open it it opens the already saved event for the outbound instead of a new event for the return.  Thus, the wrong data and I have no option to save it (since the event already exists).

This is happening on both iPhone (safari browser) and an Android phone (chrome).  No problems on the desktop.  Closing the calendar app doesn't help.

It only happens if I add the first event to the calendar - if I just back without saving there there is no problem.  It doesn't matter if I try the outbound or return first, the first one added to the calendar takes over! If I delete that from the calendar, I can then add the other one.

Each has a file name which includes the route (so the outbound and return have different file names) given in a Content-Disposition header.  I also ensure a new copy is always used.  The full headers (before echoing the contents of the ics file and dieing) are:

```
header( 'Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate', true ); // HTTP/1.1
header( 'Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT', true ); // Date in the past
header( 'Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8', true );
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"', true );
header( 'HTTP/1.0 200 OK', true, 200 );
```

I'm kind of out of ideas at this point.

Answer (score 0):

OK.  Turns out the phones were correct and outlook was wrong.  The back-end was re-using the email address as UID, so all the events had the same UID...

I have fixed the back-end code to use a more sensible UID now.  And it works

Comment: Glad you figured it out and posted back.  That's exactly what it sounded like the problem was.